# Problema Para Visualizar Dados Json View Blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, foreach

Olá! Já fiz várias tentativas e estou com dificuldade para visualizar os dados de um Json numa View.

Estou passando esses dados assim no Controller:

```
$validatorES = new EntradaSaidaFormRequest();
if(!$validatorES->validar($request)){
   $errors = $validatorES->messages();    
   return $this->index()->with(compact('errors'));
}
```

Na View:

```
<div class="container col-sm-9">
    @if (!$errors->isEmpty())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <ul>            
            @foreach ($errors as $error)
            {{ $error }}
            @endforeach 
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

A minha variável $errors está assim:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 13:53:30 GMT {"errors":{"descricao":["The descricao field is required."],"registro":["The registro field is required."]}}
```

Mas, eu não consigo imprimir essa variável na View com o Foreach acima. Estou recebendo o seguinte erro como retorno:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolveu pra mim, da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="container col-sm-9">
@if (!$errors->isEmpty())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <ul>
        {!! str_replace('"errors":', ' ', $errors->getContent()) !!}
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Como é uma área vermelha de exibição de erros de preenchimento de formulário, vou exibir o conteúdo da variável da seguinte forma: $errors->getContent(), sem exibir as outras informações que estavam sendo carregadas.

Também utilizei str_replace para retirar a palavra errors. A variável passou a ser impressa na tela assim:

```
{ {"descricao":["The descricao field is required."],"registro":["The registro field is required."]}}
```

Não é a solução que eu queria mas, me atende dessa forma. Vou personalizar depois as mensagens de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Kenia, Acredito que sua variável $errors não seja uma string. É na verdade um array de array's contendo os erros de cada input. Por isso o erro, pois `{{}}` representa um echo em um array, **no seu caso**. Você pode dar um `var_dump($errors)` na sua view para entender melhor.
Vejo que você está usando o recurso de FormRequest. 
Só a nível de simplificação,por usar o recurso FormRequest, o método $validatorES->validated() já cuidaria de devolver um array com seus dados validados (de acordo com a validação do arquivo EntradaSaidaFormRequest). Ou então, em caso de erro na validação, ele já cuida de redirecionar disponibilizando a variável $errors (que é um objeto). Exemplo:

```
$validatorES = new EntradaSaidaFormRequest();
//abaixo, o método já cuida de redirecionar ou devolver um array com dados aprovados pela validação do arquivo FormRequest criado
$validators = $validatorES->validated();
```

Na view, como $errors será um objeto, os erros são acessados assim :

```
@if($errors->has('name_do_input'))
    $errors->first('name_do_input')
@endif
```

Ou para acessar todos os erros relativos a um único input

```
@if($errors->has('name_do_input'))
    @foreach($errors->get('name_do_input') as $error)
        {{$error}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Segue a documentação para detalhes :
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation

Comment: A sua solução é muito válida mas, eu segui um caminho diferente até porque eu não fiz da forma que deveria. Eu utilizei um único Controller pra fazer insert em duas tabelas diferentes o que dificultou um pouco realizar as coisas (lição para as próximas implementações).